# <u> tag inside a <ul> element underlines even the bullet point

Tags: itext

I want to convert the following stream to pdf. while i do so bullets are also underlined even i have given `<u> tag inside <li> tag`. I want to do this in c# application. I'm using itextsharp dll for this. Have given the stream below.

```
<Form Title="iTextsharp <u> inside <ul> issue" Scrollable="True"><![CDATA[

<p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx </p>
<p><b><u>xxxxxx:</u></b>  Description </p>
    <ul>
        <li>xxxxxxxxxx common occurrences.</li>
        <li>yyyyyyyy.</li>
        <li>Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaia.</li>
        <li>bbbbbbbbbbbb.</li>
        <li>cccccccccccccccccc.</li>
        <li>ddddddddddddddddddddddddd.</li>     
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><b><u>xxxxxxxx </u>(xxxxxxxxxxxxxx):</b></li>
        <ul style="list-style-type:none">
            <li>asdfasdadasdaasdadasdasdasd.</li>
        </ul>
    <li><b><u>xmnxcvbzxnmn </u>(kjdbvdbvbdvbsdakvjsdkjvkjdsvjkdjvjkdfv):</b></li>
        <ul style="list-style-type:none">
            <li>abc.</li>
            <li>abc</li>
            <li>vabc</li>
            <li>abc</li>            
        </ul>
    <li><b><u>abc </u>abc:</b> abc.</li>
    <li><b><u>abc:</u></b> abc.</li>
</ul>

<p><b><u>abc:</u></b> abcabcabcabcabcabc:</p>

<ul>
    <li><b><u>abc:</u></b> xxxxxxxxxx.</li>
    <li><b><u>abc:</u></b> xxxxxxxxxx.</li>
    <li><b><u>abc:</u></b> xxxxxxxxxx.</li>
    <li><b><u>abc:</u></b> xxxxxxxxxx.</li>
    <li><b><u>abc:</u></b> xxxxxxxxxx.</li>
</ul>

<p>xxxxxxxxxx.</p>

<br>
<p>xxxxxxxxxx.</p>
<br>
<b>xxxxxxxxxx:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<u>xxxxxxxxxx</u></b>

]]><StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10"><StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MarginTop="10"><CheckBox Title="Windows" Margin="4" /><CheckBox Title="MAC" Margin="4" /><CheckBox Title="Linux" Margin="4" /></StackPanel><StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10"></StackPanel><StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"><Label Title="Relationship" Margin="10" /><RadioButton Name="radio" Margin="5"><Items><ListItem Value="38" Name="Self" /><ListItem Value="39" Name="Parent" /><ListItem Value="40" Name="Guardian" /></Items></RadioButton></StackPanel></StackPanel></Form>
```